# What does getText() return for an empty EditText?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to check if the EditText is empty. For this, I tried this:

```
  String text = gateNumberEditText.getText().toString();
  if (text.equals("")){
      \\do something
  } else {
       \\do something else
  }
```

Also tried: text == null  ,  text == ""  ,  text.equals(null)

Nothing seems to work, it always passes to the else. Why is that?

**isEmpty() solved my problem. 
But I'll be happy if someone explain me why it didn't work at first?

Comment: have you tried printing the value? did you try a .trim() on it? remember, " " and "" are not the same. You should use equals, not the other ones. Either way, you are not getting null, or the toString() would have thrown an NPE. Why do you call toString() on a String anyway?

Comment: gateNunberEditText.getText == null. Check this.

Comment: @Rektirino no, it can't be null

Comment: Try with: text.trim().isEmpty();

Comment: @Stultuske I tried printing it, it showed nothing (like-""). I tried trim it didnt work, and I have to  do toString() cause it is a TextView and getText() gives an Editable

Comment: @talitshakian that means you have spaces in that field. if text was an empty String, it would not go to the else block.

Comment: @Stultuske I know I have no spaces since first I set the EditText to null and then tried to check its text but still it didnt work

Comment: what do you mean, you set the EditText to null?

Comment: gateNumberEditText.setText(null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A summary of my previous comments:

```
String text = gateNumberEditText.getText().toString();
  if (text.equals("")){

                \\do something
            }else {
                \\do something else
            }
```

If you had a `null`, this code would have thrown a `NullPointerException` on the `toString()` method call.

Seeing as `getText()` returns a `String`, there is no reason to call `toString()`

When you want to compare values of `String` objects, always use the `equals(IgnoreCase)()` method.

Also, remember, `" "` (a space) and `""` are not two identical values, so comparing them will indeed return `false`.
Change your code to this:

```
String text = gateNumberEditText.getText().trim();
// the trim() method will remove all leading and trailing spaces
  if (text.isEmpty()){ // this method of the String class, will check the length of the String.
// after the trim(), for an empty String (or only spaces), that would be zero
                \\do something
            }else {
                \\do something else
            }
```

Comment: Thanks!! the isEmpty() did the job.

Comment: But I have to say that you do have to put toString() since the getText() method returns an Editable obj

Comment: @talitshakian my mistake. I looked at the code, but didn't google for the api of the type. in most cases: 'getText()' returns a String.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
String text = gateNumberEditText.getText().toString().trim();
if (text==null || text.equals("")) {
   // do something
}
else {
   // do something else
}
```

Comment: calling toString() on a String. Do you understand why the null check is redundant? If there is any possible way text would be null, there would be an Exception thrown before you performed the null check here

Answer (score -1):

You should use [TextUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) class's [isEmpty](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) method, which returns a boolen value, to check if the edit text is empty or not.

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString())) {
// Do something
} else{
 //Do something else
}
```

Comment: there is a perfectly good isEmpty() method in the String class. if it was null, you would have a NPE, and you are calling toString on a String ..

Comment: getText returns the Editable interface which is not String.... Also if you would check the source code of EditText you would see that the getText method never returns null

Comment: So what does it return instead of null? I checked the source cod with no success

Comment: An empty string, in the constructor u can see mText or something similar (don't remember the property's name exactly) was initialised with ""